# Creating a source directory in VB2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

So, I'm new to all this C++ and I'm slowly learning. I've run into a bit trouble though. I know how to move directories and files. I just don't know to install a directory. I have all my files ready, I just don't know how I'd go about making my program install the directory on to other computers that run it and stuff. Am I suppose have a source directory in VB that I put the files or what? Again, if anybody is confused, I'm not trying to install my program, I'm trying to create my OWN installation program.